# Atlaskit Editor Core with custom mention provider

Tags: atlaskit

I’m trying to implement a custom mention provider to the Editor Core unsuccessful because I had not found any documentation and/or example how to do it.

Any1 has a reference or real example about it? I want to use the mention plugin on the editor core without making an api call, just want to load the list of participants that are already load before.